How can I avoid overlap when assigning two elements the same CSS grid area?
I have markup with the following structure. I would like to have a responsive layout with three break points that works as follows:

Large viewport, three columns:
".......  nav      ........"
"toc-pkg  preamble toc-page"
"toc-pkg  content  toc-page"


Medium viewport, two columns, with in the toc grid area both toc-page and toc-pkg
following one after the other:
" nav      ..." 
" preamble toc"
" content  toc"


Narrow viewport one columns:
" nav      "
" preamble " 
" toc-page " 
" content  " 
" toc-pkg  " 



While it's easy to get the first and third layout. I can't get the second one. If I try to assign both toc-page and toc-pkg to the toc grid area they overlap (as expected it seems), but I'd like them to stack.
Is there any solution that involves a single markup structure and only CSS?


.grid>* {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav {
  height: 1em;
  background: #3C354F;
  color: white;
  grid-area: nav;
}

.toc-page {
  height: 4em;
  width: 100%;
  background: #E0695E;
  grid-area: toc-page;
}

.toc-pkg {
  height: 2em;
  width: 100%;
  background: #E0695E;
  grid-area: toc-pkg;
}

.content {
  height: 10em;
  background: #DFD4C7;
  grid-area: content;
}

.preamble {
  height: 6em;
  background: #F3F3E3;
  grid-area: preamble;
}

.tocs {
  display: flex;
  grid-area: tocs;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: start;
  align-items: center
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  gap: 1rem;
}

.grid {
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-areas: ". nav ." "toc-page preamble toc-pkg" "toc-page content toc-pkg";
}

@media (max-width: 40em) {
  .toc-page {
    grid-area: toc;
  }
  .toc-pkg {
    grid-area: toc;
  }
  .grid {
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-template-areas: "nav ." "preamble toc" "content toc";
  }
}

@media (max-width: 30em) {
  .toc-page {
    grid-area: toc-page;
  }
  .toc-pkg {
    grid-area: toc-pkg;
  }
  .grid {
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-template-areas: "nav" "preamble" "toc-page" "content" "toc-pkg";
  }
}

body {
  margin: 1rem;
}
<div class="grid medium">
  <div class="nav">NAV</div>
  <div class="preamble">PRE</div>
  <div class="toc-page">TOC-PAGE</div>
  <div class="toc-pkg">TOC-PKG</div>
  <div class="content">TXT</div>
</div>




Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself  preferably in a Stack Snippet using the <> icon.. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link.

@Paulie_D suggested using display: contents (thanks!). By tweaking the markup to
<div class="grid medium">
  <div class="nav">NAV</div>
  <div class="preamble">PRE</div>
  <div class="tocs"
    <div class="toc-page">TOC-PAGE</div>
    <div class="toc-pkg">TOC-PKG</div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">TXT</div>
</div>

Allows this to be made to work as:


.grid > * {  display: flex; justify-content: center; 
         align-items: center;  }
.nav { height: 1em; background: #3C354F; color: white; grid-area: nav; }
.toc-page { height: 4em; width: 100%; background: #E0695E; 
        grid-area: toc-page; }
.toc-pkg  { height: 2em; width: 100%; background: #E0695E; 
        grid-area: toc-pkg; }
.content { height: 10em; background: #DFD4C7; grid-area: content; }
.preamble { height: 5em; background: #F3F3E3; grid-area: preamble; }
.grid { grid-template-rows: auto; display: grid; gap: 1rem;}
.tocs { display: contents; grid-area: unset; }
.grid {
   grid-template-areas: 
 ". nav ."
 "toc-page preamble toc-pkg"
 "toc-page content toc-pkg";
 }

@media (max-width: 80em) {
  .toc-page { grid-area: unset; }
  .toc-pkg { grid-area: unset; }
  .tocs { display: block; grid-area: toc }
  .grid {
  grid-template-areas: 
"nav ."
"preamble toc"
"content toc";
}
}

@media (max-width: 60em) {
  .toc-page { grid-area: toc-page; }
  .toc-pkg { grid-area: toc-pkg; }
  .tocs { display: contents; grid-area: unset }
  .grid {
 grid-template-areas: 
  "nav"
  "preamble" 
  "toc-page"
  "content"
  "toc-pkg";
  }
}
body { margin: 1rem; }
 <div class="grid medium">
  <div class="nav">NAV</div>
  <div class="preamble">PRE</div>
  <div class="tocs">
<div class="toc-page">TOC-PAGE</div>
<div class="toc-pkg">TOC-PKG</div>
  </div>
  <div class="content">TXT</div>
</div>




At the required break-point switch the flow to column and adjust the areas to extend the preamble across two rows.
  .preamble {
    grid-row: span 2;
  }

  .grid {
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-template-areas: 
      "nav ." 
      "preamble toc-page" 
      "preamble toc-pkg" 
      "content .";
  }

I swapped out the height of the .preamble for a   min-height: 6em; but this is just a matter of preference.


.grid>* {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.nav {
  height: 1em;
  background: #3c354f;
  color: white;
  grid-area: nav;
}

.toc-page {
  height: 4em;
  width: 100%;
  background: #e0695e;
  grid-area: toc-page;
}

.toc-pkg {
  height: 2em;
  width: 100%;
  background: #e0695e;
  grid-area: toc-pkg;
}

.content {
  height: 10em;
  background: #dfd4c7;
  grid-area: content;
}

.preamble {
  min-height: 6em;
  background: #f3f3e3;
  grid-area: preamble;
}

.tocs {
  display: flex;
  grid-area: tocs;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: start;
  align-items: center;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  gap: .25rem;
}

.grid {
  grid-template-rows: auto;
  grid-template-areas: ". nav ." "toc-page preamble toc-pkg" "toc-page content toc-pkg";
}

@media (max-width: 40em) {
  .grid {
    grid-auto-flow: column;
  }
  .preamble {
    grid-row: span 2;
  }
  .toc-page {
    grid-area: toc-page;
  }
  .toc-pkg {
    grid-area: toc-pkg;
  }
  .grid {
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-template-areas: "nav ." "preamble toc-page" "preamble toc-pkg" "content .";
  }
}

@media (max-width: 30em) {
  .toc-page {
    grid-area: toc-page;
  }
  .toc-pkg {
    grid-area: toc-pkg;
  }
  .grid {
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-template-areas: "nav" "preamble" "toc-page" "content" "toc-pkg";
  }
}

body {
  margin: 1rem;
}
<div class="grid medium">
  <div class="nav">NAV</div>
  <div class="preamble">PRE</div>
  <div class="toc-page">TOC-PAGE</div>
  <div class="toc-pkg">TOC-PKG</div>
  <div class="content">TXT</div>
</div>




This aligns the tocs on preamble which is not what I want. However your comment about display: contents allows me to solve the problem (see https://jsfiddle.net/gmuyt7jb/) do you want to post an answer with this that I accept ? Otherwise I will post it.

You can post it is you want. I assumed you could not change the HTML.
